# Where can I find the sprite base grid?

Tags: pixel-art

There's been many times where I've seen people use this tile grid. It's the one with the base pink background with deep purple bands around each section. Is this available online or will I have to make it myself?

Comment: I am not sure which one you are talking about, so an example would be helpful. However, each game uses a different grid size, and many games different grid sizes for different objects, so you would likely have to create your own anyway.

Comment: Why do you think you need the 'grid' graphic? Note that the lines in the grid are not part of the game or graphic, but are usually generated by the tool used to *create* the graphic. For example in Photoshop you can enable 'the grid' by choosing 'View'->'show gridlines' from the menu.

Comment: The pink background is a very common way to represent transparency in textures that use an indexed palette. As a result, there are probably thousands of sprite sheets out there that match your description. Is it really the pink & purple colouration you care about, or something about the content of the sprite sheet, like the way the tiles are arranged (eg. for grouping autotiling sets)? Telling us more about the problem you're trying to solve with this might help us narrow-in on useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

Unfortunately, as Philipp mentioned, depending on your game it is unlikely that the grid would match your needs exactly. The one above is a 16px by 16px grid. For anything more specific, you'll probably have to make it yourself.

There is an answer on [GraphicsDesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/40783/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-blank-8-by-8-sprite-sheets-in-paint-net) that shows how to make one using paint.net.